# Getting a byte value using stringstream

Tags: c++, iostream, stringstream

I've got this (incorrect) sample code for getting a value out of stringstream and storing it in a byte-sized variable (it needs to be in a single byte var, not an int):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    stringstream ss( "1" );

    unsigned char c;
    ss >> c;

    cout << (int) c << endl;
}
```

The output when I run this is 49, which is not what I would like to see.  Obviously, this is being treated as a char and not simple numeric value.  What is the most c++ish way to get c to hold a 1 rather than a 49 when casted to an int?

Thanks!

Comment: Try the string: "\01". Or set up a char array and initialize with { 1, 0 }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The most C++-ish way is certainly to *parse* the value properly by reading into another integral type, and *then* cast to a byte type (since reading into a `char` will never parse – it will always just read the next character):

```
typedef unsigned char byte_t;

unsigned int value;
ss >> value;
if (value > numeric_limits<byte_t>::max()) {
    // Error …
}

byte_t b = static_cast<byte_t>(value);
```

I’ve used `unsigned int` since that’s the most natural, although `unsigned short` would of course also work.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was hoping there was some formatting flag, but a cast works too.

Answer (score 3):

A char will always do that.  You need to read an int (or float or double, etc) or else the wrong 'formatter' will be called.

```
unsigned char c;
unsigned int i;
ss >> i;
c = i;
```

Answer (score 2):

Subtract `'0'` from it:

```
cout << (int) (c - '0') << endl;
```

`'0'` has a value of 48, so therefore 49 - 48 = 1

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the correct value stored in the actual var.

Answer (score 0):

```
stringstream ss( "1" );
unsigned char c;
{
    unsigned int i;
    ss >> i;
    c = i;
}
cout << static_cast<int>(c) << endl;
```

Will work.  You could also do some unsafe pointer stuff but I would just go with the above.

Answer (score -1):

That's because string constants in C++ are treated like text.
Two options:

- Encode the string using escaped numbers:

  - Octal Numbers:  \0<d>{1,3}
  - Hex Numbers:    \0x<d>{2}

  std::stringstream( "\01\02\03\04\0xFF");
- Or build an array of char and initialize it using numbers:

  char data[] = { 0, 1, 2,3 ,4, 255 };

How about:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char x[] = {1,0};
    stringstream ss( x);

    unsigned char c;
    ss >> c;

    cout << (int) c << endl;
}
```