# A story of stringstream, hexadecimal and characters

Tags: c++

I have a string containing hexadecimal values (two characters representing a byte). I would like to use `std::stringstream` to make the conversion as painless as possible, so I came up with the following code:

```
std::string a_hex_number = "e3";

{
    unsigned char x;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << a_hex_number;
    ss >> x;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

To my biggest surprise this prints out `"e"` ... Of course I don't give up so easily, and I modify the code to be:

```
{
    unsigned short y;
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::hex << a_hex_number;
    ss >> y;
    std::cout << y << std::endl;
}
```

This, as expected, prints out `227` ...

I looked at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/hex/ but I just could not find a reference which tells me more about why this behaviour comes ...(yes, I feel that it is right because when extracting a character it should take one character, but I am a little bit confused that `std:hex` is ignored for `char`acters). Is there a mention about this situation somewhere?

(http://ideone.com/YHt7Fz)

**Edit** I am specifically interested if this behaviour is mentioned in any of the STL standards.

Comment: This behaviour occurs because `char` and `unsigned char` are treated as *character* data types rather than *integer data types* by the streams.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a byte value using stringstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356661/getting-a-byte-value-using-stringstream)

Comment: @40two I agree, it is a very similar issue, however I am interested specifically if this behaviour is mentioned in any of the standards out there.

Comment: I'll retract, but please be so kind as to clarify this in your question.

Comment: These are the relevant operators: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2

Comment: [istream::extractors]/12-13 [sic, ::] says `operator>>` for character types extracts a single character. As opposed to arithmetic extractors for other integer types such as `short`, which use the locale and `num_get` [istream.formatted.arithmetic].

Comment: @dyp would fit nicely in an answer box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're trying to convert a string in
hex to an `unsigned char`.  So for starters, since this is
"input", you should be using `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream ss( a_hex_number );
ss >> std::hex >> variable;
```

Beyond that, you want the input to parse the string as an
integral value.  Streams do *not* consider character types as
numeric values; they read a single character into them (after
skipping leading white space).  To get a numeric value, you
should input to an `int`, and then convert that to `unsigned
char`.  Characters don't have a base, so `std::hex` is
irrelevant for them.  (The same thing holds for strings, for
example, and even for floating point.)

With regards to the page you site: the page doesn't mention
inputting into a character type (strangely enough, because it
does talk about all other types, including some very special
cases).  The documentation for the `std::hex` manipulator is
also weak: in the running text, it only says that "extracted
values are also expected to be in hexadecimal base", which isn't
really correct; in the table, however, it clearly talks about
"integral values".  In the standard, this is documented in
§27.7.2.2.3.  (The `>>` operators for character types are *not*
member functions, but free functions, so are defined in
a different section.)  What we are missing, however, is a good
document which synthesizes these sort of things: whether the
`>>` operator is a member or a free function doesn't really
affect the user much; you want to see all of the `>>` available,
with their semantics, in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Let's put it simple: variable type is 'stronger' than 'hex'. That's why 'hex' is ignored for 'char' variable.

Longer story:
'Hex' modifies internal state of stringstream object telling it how to treat subsequent operations on **integers**. However, this does not apply to **chars**.

Comment: I agree, but is this mentioned in the stl standard anywhere?

Comment: @fritzone `operator>>` for `char` types is not an arithmetic extractor [istream.formatted.arithmetic].

Comment: Here is documentation site from one major STL 'provider' [link](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/)

Answer (score 0):

When you print out a character (i.e. `unsigned char`), it's printed as a character, not as a number.